# Python Style - Should statements be nested inside a context manager that do not require the context?

Tags: python, with-statement, pep8, contextmanager

Is there style guidance or reason to prefer one of these patterns over the other?

Minimizing the amount of code under the context manager "feels" cleaner to me, but I can't point to a specific reason why. It may be that this is just preference and there is no official guidance on the matter.

1) All code inside with context.

```
with open(file) as f:
    text = f.read()
    data = text.split(',')
    result = my_func(data)
    # etc.
```

2) Only necessary code inside with context.

```
with open(file) as f:
    text = f.read()

data = text.split(',')
result = my_func(data)
# etc.
```

Comment: the latter is clean, crisp and easy to follow. (in my eyes atleast)

Comment: I prefer the 2nd

Comment: It depends what you call official: "Flat is better than nested." is part of the [zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3)

Comment: I've voted to close this question as opinion-based, but FWIW I go with 2. Just like `try-except` blocks, try to have them as small and relevant as possible. As a bonus you also "save" an indentation level

Comment: I imagine long processes in the with block could lock a resource such as an open connection or possibly a file object but it's one of those that I've wondered about but not tested. I've always tried to leave the block as soon as I have no reason to be in it any more anyway.

Comment: @roganjosh That's a totally valid point.

Answer (score 0):

I think readability is always the guideline in the absence of any "style guide" statements - you want to easily see all uses of the context manager variable ('f' above) while it's in scope. The difference between a one and four line block to that visibility isn't significant, but between three lines and 50 it probably is.